# Find the integral $\int \frac{1}{x^2 \cdot \tan(x)} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

This problem seems pretty tricky. I need to find the integral of

$$\int \dfrac{1}{x^2 \cdot \tan(x)} \ dx$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try integration-by-parts with $ \ u = x^{-2} \ $ and $ \ v = \ln(\sin x) \ . $

Comment: @user133707 indefinite integral? wolfram fails.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: I also just checked wolfram alpha. Standard time exceeds ^^.

Comment: Yes, I just found that, too:  continuing to work along on this, I don't think it liked the $ \ \int v \ du \ $ ... What is the context for this problem?  It doesn't look like there will be a closed-form anti-derivative; I'm not even finding related integrals that have one...

Comment: I'm sure this integral can't be done in closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Applying limits from 0 to $\pi/2$ might make it solvable though. Just a thought, since I just solved something similar. $\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot(x)\,dx$

Comment: Yes, it is easy to see that $\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dx}{x^2 \tan(x)} = \infty$.

Comment: Not only that it possesses no closed form, but it can't even be expressed in terms of [trigonometric integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral). See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the decomposition of $\frac{1}{\tan x}$ into simple fractions:

$$\frac{1}{\tan x}=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2x}{x^2-n^2\pi^2}$$ So

$$\frac{1}{x^2\tan x}=\frac{1}{x^3}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(x^2-n^2\pi^2)}$$ and

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\tan x}=-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\frac{\left |x^2-n^2\pi^2  \right |}{x^2}}{n^2\pi^2}+\text{const}$$

This is of course a matter of taste, whether the form is closed or not.

Answer (score 0):

$\int x^{-2}(\tan x)^{-1}=\int x^{-2}\cot x$

then by parts u=$\cot x$, dv=$x^{-2}$

$\int x^{-2}\cot x= -x^{-1}\cot x-\int (-x^{-1})(-\csc^2x)=\int x^{-1}(-\csc^2x)-x^{-1}\cot x )$

Thus $$ \int \frac {1}{x^2\tan x}= \frac {-\cot x}{x}-\int \frac {csc^2x}{x}+c$$

Yep, no closed form